# How do i return data from a database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rxjs

I cant subscribe to an observable returned by a stored procedure on server-side.

Im trying to call a stored procedure on a controller, like this

```js
alerts: async ( req, res, next ) => {
            try{ 
                let id_user = req.params.id
                let res_array = []
                return await Database.knex.raw( 'CALL getAlerts( ? )', [id_user] ).then( response => {
                    response[0][0].map( res => {
                        res_array.push(res)
                    })
                    return  res_array
                 } )

            } catch ( error ) {
                return next( error );
            }
        }
```

This is called on a component by using

```
this.api.get('alerts/'+ this.auth.user.id).subscribe( (alerts: any)  => {
            console.log("subscribing", alerts)
        })
```

Through the route

```
router.get('/alerts/:id', controller.alerts);
```

The SP returns the correct values, but when I try to subscribe to access them on the component, I cant see the console log, or do anything with that observable.
Why is this? I read as much as I could on the subject but I still can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you return something from Express.js. You should refactor to something like:

```
alerts: (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    Database.knex.raw('CALL getAlerts( ? )', [id])
        .then(response => response[0][0])
        .then(res.send)
        .then(() => next())
        .catch(next)
}
```

Comment: I tried to return the values this way, but im running into "Cannot read property 'req' of undefined", which is weird because im not referencing anything.req, and the req.params logs correctly. however, I will have a look at the express docs. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Indeed this is weird, and certainly not related to the code you shared in this question